# Full array not being passed in C

Tags: c, algorithm, insertion-sort

I'm working on an insertion sort and my array in main() seems to only be partially passed to sort(). The snippet below shows that `test` in main() has the value `{2, 1, 3, 1, 2}`, but `arr` in sort() has the value `{2, 1}`. What's going on here?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int sort(int* arr) {
      int i = 0;
      int j, key;
      int count = 0;

      printf("Inside sort(): ");
      for (j = 0; j < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); ++j)
           printf("%d ", arr[j]);
      printf("\n");

      for (j = 1; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); ++j) {
           key = arr[j];
           i = j - 1;
           while (i >= 0 && arr[i] > key) {
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                --i;
                ++count;
           }
           arr[i + 1] = key;
      }
      return count;
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv) {
      int test[] = {2, 1, 3, 1, 2};
      int i = 0;
      printf("Inside main(): ");
      for (i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(int); ++i)
           printf("%d ", test[i]);
      printf("\n");
      int count = sort(test);
 }
```

Comment: The lesson to learn from this is to pass the size of the array to the function you are calling.  Do not try to make the function determine the size of the array.  In general, the function cannot determine the size.  In a few selected special cases, it is possible (for example, there's a null pointer at the end of an array of pointers).  It is not an accident that the argument list for `main()` is `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, even though that is one of the special cases where the null pointer can be used to determine the end of the list of arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiom `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` only works for statically-allocated arrays, and only within the scope that defines them.

In other words, you can use it for arrays like:

```
int foo[32];
```

...in the scope in which they're defined. But not elsewhere, and not for arrays simply passed as pointers. For other cases, you'll need to pass along extra information indicating the expected number of elements in the array.

Comment: So something like `int sort(int* arr, int size)`?

Comment: Exacly. Or better even `size_t size`

Comment: @BrewerHimself Yep, that would do just fine :) Just be clear on whether `size` is the size of the array in bytes or number of contained elements.

Comment: @reuben `size = sizeof(test)/sizeof(int)`. How's that?

Comment: @wildplasser What are the benefits of `size_t` over `int`?

Comment: @BrewerHimself Number of elements is fine. I just made the point so as to avoid potential confusion in code...

Comment: 1) It is unsigned. 2) it is large enough to express any size (in memory) BTW : `size = sizeof test /sizeof test[0]` is cleaner, because it does not depend on the actual type of test[0] (it would require no changes if you changed the type of test to a double or a struct xyz)

Comment: Your basic diagnosis is correct, but I'm not convinced that you should use 'statically' in 'statically-allocated'.  The idiom works fine with global arrays as long as you can see the definition, not just a declaration; similarly with local arrays, including VLA.  The crucial point is that it does not work with arguments to functions, and that it does not work with mere declarations of the array visible.

Comment: @BrewerHimself, if you have C99, `int sort(size_t size, int arr[size])` would be best as an interface. This clearly shows the intention of it, and it helps you the day you start to have multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @JensGustedt What is the reasoning for providing a size to `int arr[]`? Is there any difference between `int arr[]` and `int arr[size]` other than explicitly stating the length of `int arr[]`?

Comment: The difference only becomes real when you have 2D arrays. Only the first dimension is silently changed to a pointer. For `int toto(size_t size, int arr[size][size])` the compiler would  do the arithmetic of `arr[i][j]` for you. So I think it is better to just do it always like this, easier to read and no surprises when you go to 2d.